# Add to cart not working using magento version 2.2.4

Tags: magento, cart

When I click add to cart it goes to cart page and shows "You have no items in your shopping cart."
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hrnV.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to change your browser. When I change my Chrome to firefox, it works